# What is the most common waste of computing power in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

We've all seen people who do this:

```
jQuery('a').each(function(){
    jQuery(this)[0].innerHTML += ' proccessed';
});

function letsPoluteNS() {
    polute = '';
    for (morePolution = 0; morePolution < arguments.length; morePolution++)
        polute.join(arguments[morePolution]);
    return polute;
}
```

and so on. I was wondering what people have seen the most common JavaScript/jQuery technique that is slowing down the page and/or wasting time for the JavaScript engine.

I know that this question may not seem to fit into what's an accepted question, yet I'm asking "what is the most common accepted waste?"

Comment: How do you judge "most common accepted waste"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guilt of this. Basically using only the element's class in a jQuery selector. Instead of combining the class selector with the elements tag name.

```
<div></div>
<div class="hide"></div>
<div class="show"></div>
<div class="hide"></div>
<div class="hide again"></div>
```

---

```
$(".hide").hide();
```

Instead of the quicker

```
$("div.hide").hide()
```

---

---

Also this is inefficient, many people don't make use of the context parameter for selectors

[$( selector, [ context ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

---

```
   $("#mydiv").click(function () {
      $("#mydiv span").show();
   }
```

Which can be handled better like this:

```
   $("#mydiv").click(function () {
      $("span", this).show();
   }
```

Comment: What? `#hello` is definitely the quicker one (`document.getElementById()` notwithstanding).

Comment: yeah getElementById is much faster than {getElementByClassname->getElementById}, even without the overhead

Comment: `$("#hello")` is essentially the same as `getElementById('hello');` which is a very efficient way to get a dom element.  Adding an additional tag name to the selector isn't helping.

Comment: Oh you meant class. \*facepalm\*

Comment: @BoltClock , @qwertymk, @box9  Sorry guys its late and I meant to say class not id. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that has do to with tracking users and heavy publicity. Thats wasted space for sure.

I guess wrong use of stuff like using classes instead ids as selector in very complex html would slow thing down.
And [ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496401/jerky-animation-with-jquery-accordion-dont-understand-why) of course.

Comment: you can make it even slower by changing it to z>1000

Comment: @JCOC611 also for (i=0;i<1000;i++)for(j=0;j<1000;j++);;proccessresponse();

Comment: @travelboy changing to `z>1000` will make the loop not run at all ;) I think you meant `z--`

Comment: @box9: right… *blush* yeah, this performance stuff is advanced! :)

Comment: lol how about M$'s implementation `MakeIESlow()`?? Lol, it's set to default XD

Answer (score 1):

You'll also see this:

```
$('#this').find('a').doSomeThing();
```

Know what's a lot more efficient?  One selector that covers both will server you better...

```
$('#this a').doSomeThing();
```

It seems obvious, but you'll see it all the time.

Comment: Actually, not true. The first one is faster as it delegates directly to `document.getElementById()` to narrow the search down.

Comment: So looping over the selected set is more efficient?  I always understood a single selector to be the preferred method.

Comment: It depends. Things that can be handled directly by the browser is always faster. The clearest example is `getElementById()`, but if the browser supports `getElementsByName`, `getElementsByTagName` or `querySelectorAll`, then it will be faster to supply a selector that can be directly handled by those functions and filter the results using jQuery methods.

Answer (score 0):

Calling $.animate to animate elements should make the things slow down.

Answer (score 0):

not declaring your vars from the getgo so they are cached, not using closures and repeating x number of the same function/call/etc but only changing id or class for each, using eval().