# Jerky animation with jquery accordion, don't understand why

Tags: jquery, accordion, anythingslider

I'm using a number of jQueryUI accordions on a single page inside of AnythingSlider. It used to be that it was pretty smooth, but has gotten jerky.

Now, instead inserting a bunch of code, how about I just give the link and you can look. If it works fine for you, then, well, I just don't know. Of course, if there's more you'd like to have, let me know.

[Click here](http://bigsilkdesign.com/comida/)

Comment: Very smooth for me in Google Chrome with a system that could outrun a horse.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fin, smooth and all.

Answer (score 1):

I've got an aged laptop that sometimes lags behind my year-old Android phone.  Your accordions looked slick in Chrome, a little less so in FireFox, and the site was utterly trashed and unintelligible in IE7.

Comment: Are you looking at it in compatibility view in IE7? I did, hosed. Turned it off, worked well. Yeah FF is what I default to, and that's what's making it do bad.